# JSON serialization technicalities in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

What is the difference between the following serialization methods?

1. First Method

   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list or datatable)

and the output is

i.e.  (3) [Object, Object, Object]

2. Second Method

```html
Dim parent = Prtdata
                Dim lGridColumns = New With {
                    Key .data = parent
                        }
                Dim Setting = New JsonSerializerSettings
                Setting.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                Dim jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lGridColumns, Formatting.Indented)
                Return jsonObject
```

and its output is

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "RecID": 2383,
      "PrtStatus": 0,
      "PtFilenum": 15090248,
      "PrtFilenum": 13090701,
      "FullName": "asdasd",
      "DOB": "04 Oct 1985"
    },
    {
      "RecID": 3387,
      "PrtStatus": 1,
      "PtFilenum": 15090248,
      "PrtFilenum": 15120996,
      "FullName": "marwam mohmmad  saleem",
      "DOB": "24 May 2017"
    },
    {
      "RecID": 3388,
      "PrtStatus": 1,
      "PtFilenum": 15090248,
      "PrtFilenum": 170227111,
      "FullName": "asd dsf as a",
      "DOB": "27 Feb 2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

why the output looks different in the browser console?

Comment: For the first scenario, you are creating an array (since you are serializing a list or an array), the second one is creating a json object with the data in a separate property. This would be the same in many languages, so I don't really get the question you are asking here?

Comment: you just answered it, could you please post it as an answer

Comment: Alright, I did, tried to give a bit more info than in the comment though ;)

Comment: this is what exactly I was looking for indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first comment, you can find a [Serialization Guide](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) on the website of NewtonSoft.json, in my answer I just provide a more elaborate version of my comment earlier.

The first scenario, where you are serializing something implemented [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) (eg: list, array), will be represented by an array in Json, eg:

```
[{ "property": "value", "id": 0 }, {"property": "value", "id": 1}]
```

For the second scenario, you are doing several things differently, for example you are providing the [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm) in the [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) which would also preveserve any references made in the objects you are serializing, eg:

```
[{"$id": 1, "title": "item1"}, {"$id": 2, "title": "item2", "previous": { "$ref": 1 }]
```

This would make sure that when deserialized, the second object would contain a reference to the first object, inside the property `previous`.

Another thing you are doing differently is providing the [`Formatting.Indented`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm), which will create a more reader friendly json document, having line breaks and indentation. The previous Json would then become something similar to this:

```
[{
    "$id": 1,
    "title": "item1"
},
{
    "$id": 2,
    "title": "item2",
    "previous": {
        "$ref": 1
    }
}]
```

And, the last big difference is that in the last example, you are serializing a single object, cause it's public properties to be serialized, eg:

```
{
    "data": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Where `data` is a property on the object you are serializing.